# How to override pool and reaping_frequency in heroku's database.yml

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.1, heroku-postgres

I am using heroku with Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.1. I am using default database configuration for heroku. That's why I have put database.yml into `.gitignore` and I am not using `database.yml` for production.

I am facing issue for `PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor` and for solve this error i need to set `reaping_frequency`.

> The `reaping_frequency` can tell Active Record to check to see if connections are hung or dead every N seconds and terminate them. While it is likely that over time your application may have a few connections that hang, if something in your code is causing hung connections, the reaper will not be a permanent fix to the problem.

Now I want to add this configuration into `database.yml`.

```
  reaping_frequency: 10
```

so should I directly add this configuration over `database.yml` for override or is there any another better way to set this frequency into heroku?

Thanks in advance for suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your config/unicorn.rb or config/puma.rb set pool and reaping_frequency in the config:

```
config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
            Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5
config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4.0+ can directly specify `pool` and `reaping_frequency` in `config/database.yml`.

See **Options** in following API links:

- [Rails 4.2.4 ConnectionPool API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.4/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)
- [Rails 4.1.13 ConnectionPool API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.13/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)
- [Rails 4.0.13 ConnectionPool API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.13/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)